# Save screenshot in Geomagic to specific location

Tags: python

Following method in Geomagic saves screenshot to the default app directory:

```
geo.take_snapshot()
```

This does not work: `geo.take_snapshot(u"C:\\temp\\FrontView.png")`

How can I save a screenshot to the custom location?

Comment: What is it doing when it is not working? Does it give an error? Does it crash? Does it save in the wrong directory?

Comment: Screenshot always saves to the default app location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to save screenshot to another location you need to use another method:

```
geo.screen_capture_views(u'c:\\temp\\FrontView.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that API, but searching for it I only found examples using `geo.take_snapshot()`. It looks like the default snapshot location can be configured somehow in the application, but not selected during the method call.

A workaround would be to save to the default location, then move the file to 
the desired directory:

```
import os

with open(source_path, 'rb') as snapshot:    # Read in binary mode, so filetype doesn't matter.
    with open(desired_path, 'wb') as image:
        image.write(snapshot.read())
        os.remove(source_path)
```

Comment: I'd use [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) rather than a DIY file copy.